# Is it possible to make Jenkins run a script after a job is created?

Tags: shell, jenkins

I have a code management app that integrates with Jenkins via CLI, creating, deleting and building jobs. After I create a new Jenkins job, I need to run a shell script. This script depends on some directories created by Jenkins, namely the workspace.

Jenkins CLI is non blocking, thus I can't just wait for the command to terminate. Is it possible, maybe with a plugin (I couldn't find any...), to trigger the execution of a shell script post job creation?

Comment: You can run a shell script as a build step. I think this works "out of the box" without any plugin needed.

Comment: But Jenkins doesn't build the job right after its creation. Ideally, I needed my script to be run after creation but before the first build.

Comment: Okay, now I get it ;-) Don't know a clean solution but you could wait for the directories are created in your script. Something like `while(!directoryExists) { wait(1); }` (pseudo code). Would this work for you?

Comment: Yup, that's my current approach. Wait for it to exist and call a job build after creation. It's an OK solution but this first build typically fails because one of the things my script does is setting up the virtual host that will allow Selenium tests to run. But I guess I'll have to live with that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jenkins CLI command `build` has the command option `-s` which will block the trigger action until is finished.

See YOUR_JENKINS_URL/cli